# git fork a forked fork with access to

Tags: github, git-fork

I forked a repo (https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython) on github that is itself a fork (of micropython). Both projects are active, but have gone in different directions and the "forked fork" (circuitpython) no longer tracks the original (micropython).

I use both (and would like to submit PRs to both), and ideally would like to have a fork of both projects, but that's apparently not possible on github. Hence I am looking for a workaround.

Can I for example create a branch (e.g. micropython-master) in my fork that tracks the original repo (micropython)? The existing branch "main" should continue to track the fork.